# Parsing an integer in a string?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I was going through this example on [DCG](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG)

```
integer(I) -->
        digit(D0),
        digits(D),
        { number_codes(I, [D0|D])
        }.

digits([D|T]) -->
        digit(D), !,
        digits(T).
digits([]) -->
        [].

digit(D) -->
        [D],
        { code_type(D, digit)
        }.
```

But this example parses an integer only if it's in the beginning of the string (because digit(D0) fails is D0 is not a number code).
How do I go about parsing an integer anywhere in the string, e.g.  "abc123def"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add something like this:

```
non_digits--> [D], {not(code_type(D, digit))}, !, non_digits.
non_digits-->[].
```

and then add a call to `non_digits` to skip non digits, e.g.:

```
integer_skip(I) -->
        non_digits,
        digit(D0),
        digits(D),
        { 
           number_codes(I, [D0|D])
        },
        non_digits.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I just did! non_digit --> [C], {not(code_type(C,digit))}, non_digit.
non_digit --> !. I think it's the same.